# i need help finding a new chain ring (the gears that are in-between the pedals)

Tags: chainring

I am currently fixing my pacific vector bike and I need to know where to find new chainrings, I can't find any anywhere else.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid shopping questions aren't really on-topic; perhaps if you explain why typing "bicycle chainrings" into your favourite search engine doesn't direct you to many, many sites to purchase them?

Comment: Welcome to the site - Looks like a 3x7 = 21 speed bike.  Can you add a clear photo of the chainrings from the right-hand side?  There's a chance they're rivetted together and you need an entire replacement crank, or they might be bolted on and only need a new chainring of the correct specs.

Comment: Do what Criggie asks. While we can't give specific product recommendations, we can tell you what to search for on Google.